# Wicket - Form not submitting

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-7

I just upgraded a Wicket application from 6.0.0 to 7.6.0 and now I am having problems with one of my forms not submitting.

I went through the versions and my form was working in version 6.12.0 and not working in 6.14.0 there were other problems with 6.13.0

I am using a Button and overriding the onSubmit() method. I have some logging as the first line in the method.  I also have overridden the onError() method with logging as the first line in that also.

I also removed the Button and put my code in the Form onSubmit() and onError() with logging and it still is not called in that code.

I have a FeedbackPanel on the page and no errors show up there.

I have checked the javascript console and there are no errors showing.

I also tried to change the Button into a SubmitLink and that produced the same results.

I checked over my HTML and all tags are present, again it was working in the previous version.

When these options are clicked it just refreshes the same page and resets all the values in the form to the values on the original load of the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Java
Form form = new Form("vvoForm"){
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(){
         System.out.println("comment here");//This is never called
    {

    @Override
    public void onError(){
        System.out.println("Another commment here");//This is never called
    {
}

HTML
<form wicket:id="vvoForm">
    //There is a table here with input tags all with wicket:id's and 
    //included and added to the Java code
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />//I had a wicket:id here but removed it for simplicity. The wicket:id refferenced the Button
</form>
```

Comment: Please create a mini demo application and attach it to a ticket in Wicket JIRA! The code shown above is very simple and I'm pretty sure it should work. Put a breakpoint in Form#onFormSubmitted() and follow the execution to see what goes wrong.

Comment: By this we can't sorted out your issue . it look like something else not trigger the submit at all .could you share you more info on code side?

Comment: Can you show the full page . There is a possibility  validation might be failed which failing to show the error message .